# How to compare binned CDFs?

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, cumulative-distribution-function, binning

We want to compare binned CDFs from sampled data.

Each CDF is 101 numbers representing percentiles, i.e., $P(x<a_k)=k/100$ where $k=0..100$.

The sample size is 1-3k (unknown at comparison time and different for different CDFs).

Can we use the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov-Smirnov_test)?

If yes, what are $n$ and $n'$? 100 (number of bins)? 1000 (the minimum number of observations which the CDFs are based on?

Comment: A powerful and effective way to make this comparison is to construct the QQ plot. However, your reference to the KS test suggests you are looking for a formal hypothesis test.  But what would be the purpose of that?  It's rare that such a test is needed just for its own sake.

Comment: We are trying to decide whether we can use an easily available CDF instead of a scarce one.

Comment: I'm sure you understand what you intended to write in that comment, but as a general proposition "availability" and "scarcity" of a CDF have no meaning.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: What I mean is that some things are easy to compute and others are hard to compute. Can I use this instead of that?

Comment: Once again, *for what purpose* do you wish to use these CDFs?

Comment: To map values to probabilities. E.g., find such threshold $t$ that keeping only $x>t$ will leave me with about 3% of data.